# Remove hyperlink on gallery shortcode

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I do a gallery shortcode on my index.php (theme directory) to display a 3 boxes of images. The images are fetch from my Media.

```
<div class="well well-clear" style="padding-bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">
  <?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery ids="165,166,167"]'); ?>
</div>
```

By default this images has a hyperlink that when I click on it, a page will open and show the bigger version of this image. I don't want this to have, is there any option that I need to modify so that it will not do a hyperlink?

I'm new to Wordpress, please don't be rough on me.

Answer (score 0):

The better way:

You can use [gallery](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) shortcode `link` option with value `none`.

```
<div class="well well-clear" style="padding-bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">
  <?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery ids="165,166,167" link="none"]'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: @LeandroGarcia Checked both on version `3.6` to `3.8` working perfectly here!

Comment: Now this is weird, just upgraded to 3.8 but it doesn't work either. How do you upload your image?

Comment: @LeandroGarcia Can you post your updated code? and also which template file you are echoing it?

Comment: I just followed your code suggestion, upgrade my Wordpress, still the hyperlink is present even if `link="none"` is already in the gallery shortcode. I have it on the index.php file of The Bootstrap template.

Comment: @LeandroGarcia Can you change to `link="attachment"` it will generate the attachment permalink and check does it change?.